# Storing objects of custom type in $_SESSION - legal way?

Tags: sessions

I'm trying to figure out: can I load custom class (defined in module) to be loaded before session starts and its contents processed by PHP (unserialized) - is where any legal way to do this? (without hacking Drupal core)

without it I get _PHP_Incomplete_Class if I store something of a custom type to $_SESSION variable.

I did a research:

- hook_boot is not called unless page is cached in NO DB mode otherwise it's called after session is loaded
- hook_init is called too late (always after session load)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's _'NO DB mode'_? `hook_boot()` will be called on every single request that goes through Drupal (regardless of caching status), so I'm guessing you have contrib modules installed that change that behaviour, or some core patches or something?

Comment: I mean what if You look into Drupal Core sources You'll see that bootstrap_invoke_all($hook) called 2 times one in PAGE_CACHE phase of drupal bootstrap and one in PAGE_HEADER (which is after session start)

The one which called before session start is not invoked unless there is a cached version of requested page stored not in Database.that's what i meant.

Comment: no core patching. this is that I'm trying to avoid by asking this question.

Comment: OK I think I get you, but just to confirm - you're serializing a custom class into a session variable, and at some point when you read that variable back in and `unserialize()`, PHP complains about an incomplete class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Every time I'm trying to restore something of custom type from serialized session.

Comment: Wow, that's not something I've come across before (and I'm a big fan of serialising to the session, do it all the time). Are you able to test this on a different machine to make sure your version of PHP isn't configured incorrectly?

Comment: PHP is okay. I tested it on at least 3 environments. Problems that classes are loaded after session

Comment: Does your class implement any magic methods? `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` immediately come to mind as things that could cause issues. Even `__clone()` might come into it, I'm not sure. If it's convenient, could you edit the question to include a dump of your class?

Comment: sorry, it's under NDA. This is not comes with a concrete class. (anyway mine contains only usual methods, no magic) 
problem is that I cant load class definition in memory before drupal_session_start() occurs and it leads to this error.
There are many possible solutions of my problem, e.g:
1)not to use $_SESSION - store it somethere separately and mantain load process by myself.
2)double serialize it into the session and mantain unserialization by myself.
The answer I'm trying to get: is there a way to rely on standart biuld in PHP mechanics of storing session across page requests or not

Comment: Without hacking the core - I doubt it. Even if you just registered your class to memory in index.php, before the request instantiation, that would solve the problem. Bottom line is custom code doesn't get the chance to run early on enough for what you need. I know you already know that, just trying to confirm your fears as it were

Comment: @Clive This seems crazy that there's no way to do this without double serializing. What of custom SPL autoloaders? I hear they're all the thing in D8, is there a way to do in D7? I suppose I could hack ./includes/bootstrap.inc and add an autoloader in there?

Comment: @artfulrobot Yeah Drupal 8's architecture is completely different, the autoloader probably needs to be registered for the session handling code to even be included. I've just had another look and I still can't see a way to do it in D7 without patching a core file somewhere. Might be missing something though

Comment: Yep. Luckily for me I'm designing my own objects for a new project, so I have a work-around: create a class that binds an internal var to a sess var, where the var is a plain array (or StdClass) structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, I have found a workaround to do so without patching the core.

it is simple.

Drupal 7 core includes all module files which have `hook_boot()` registred, prior to open session, but `hook_boot()` is called only then session is started.

What you need to do - is to manually include class declaration outside of a `hook_boot()` (in a root context of a file containing `hook_boot()` of your module).

Such code is immediately executed as file being included by Drupal Core (prior to `session_start()` call), which gives us the desired behavior - we now can store objects of a *CustomClass* in `$_SESSION` variable and they wont become corrupted on next page load.

but be carefull if your *CustomClass* is extending from *AnotherCustomClass* located in different module and loaded by same mechanics (as described above) - you cannot be sure in order file loads.
This can lead to fatal runtime error: Undefined class